# pandas groupby several criteria

Tags: pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this

[image]

which contains every minute of a year.

I need to simplify it on hourly base and to get  only hours of the year and then maximum of Reserved and Used columns for the respective hours.

I made this, which works, but not totally for my purposes

```
df = df.assign(date=df.date.dt.round('H'))
df1 = df.groupby('date').agg({'Reserved': ['max'], 'Used': ['max'] }).droplevel(1, axis=1).reset_index()
```

which just groups the minutes into hours.

```
                     date  Reserved  Used
0    2020-01-01 00:00:00      2176   0.0
1    2020-01-01 01:00:00      2176   0.0
2    2020-01-01 02:00:00      2176   0.0
3    2020-01-01 03:00:00      2176   0.0
4    2020-01-01 04:00:00      2176   0.0
...                  ...       ...   ...
8780 2020-12-31 20:00:00      3450  50.0
8781 2020-12-31 21:00:00      3450   0.0
8782 2020-12-31 22:00:00      3450   0.0
8783 2020-12-31 23:00:00      3450   0.0
8784 2021-01-01 00:00:00      3450   0.0
```

Now I need group it more to plot several curves, containing only 24 points (for every hour) based on several criteria

- average used and reserved for the whole year (so to group together every 00 hour, every 01 hour, etc.)
- average used and reserved for every month (so to group every 00 hour, 01 hour etc for each month individually)
- average used and reserved for weekdays and for weekends

I know this is only the similar groupby as before, but I somehow miss the logic of doing it.

Could anybody help?

Thanks.